# KafkaConsumer assignment() returns empty

Tags: java, scala, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am using

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

The following piece of codes returns the **non-empty assigned** partitions, but `poll(0)` deprecated.

```
val records = kafkaConsumer.poll(0) // <= deprecated
logInfo(s"Dummy call ${records.count()}")

val partitions = kafkaConsumer.assignment()
logInfo(s"partitions=${partitions}")
```

The following return **empty** partitions:

```
val records = kafkaConsumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(0)) // <= not working
logInfo(s"Dummy call ${records.count()}")

val partitions = kafkaConsumer.assignment()
logInfo(s"partitions=${partitions}")
```

Why? Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The difference of these two calls is the way the metadata is fetched. The deprecated `poll` waits indefinitely until the metadata is retrieved successfully, whereas the other `poll` only tries once, often failing to connect to the coordinator within a very shot time interval(0 for your case), and returns with nothing useful. That's why you see an empty assignment after calling `poll(Duration.ofMillis(0))` once.